# Como devolver todos los elementos de una lista en el return de un método C#

Tags: c#, lista, object

La lista que quiero devolver es una lista de objetos de la siguiente clase:

```
public class LightObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string lightType { get; set; }
    public string lightNumber { get; set; }
    public bool lightOn { get; set; }
    public long? lightHue { get; set; }
    public long lightBri { get; set; }
}
```

Quiero obtener todos los elementos de la siguiente lista:

```
LightObject[] lightsObjects = new LightObject[jsonTotalLights];
```

Esta lista se genera en este metodo:

```
public string GenerateLightsObjects()
    {
        // Obtención del JSON pidiendo la variable jsonlights al Lightipscript
        GameObject a = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        LightsIpScript b = a.GetComponent<LightsIpScript>();

        // Obtenemos el JSON
        jsonLights = b.jsonLights;

        // Obtenemos la CANTIDAD de elementos del JSON
        jsonTotalLights = b.jsonTotalOfLights;

        // Se almacena en un diccionario los objetos del JSON
        var dataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Light>>(jsonLights);

        // Almacenar el nombre de todas las bombillas
        ReadAndGetNameOfParentsFromJson(jsonLights);

        // Generar objetos de las luces
        LightObject[] lightsObjects = new LightObject[jsonTotalLights];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonTotalLights; i++)
        {
            string bombillaActual = listOfParents[i];

            lightsObjects[i] = new LightObject() {
                lightType = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].Type,
                lightOn = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].State.On,
                lightNumber = bombillaActual,
                lightHue = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].State.Hue,
                lightBri = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].State.Bri
            };

        }

        // SACAR POR CONSOLA LA LISTA DE BOMBILLAS
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonTotalLights; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("-- BOMBILLA: "+lightsObjects[i].lightNumber);
            Debug.Log("-- TIPO DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightType);
            Debug.Log("-- COLOR DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightHue);
            Debug.Log("-- BRILLO DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightBri);
            Debug.Log("-- ESTADO DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightOn);
            Debug.Log("valor de la I: "+i);
        }

        return jsonLights;
    }
```

Actualmente devuelve un string y el método está creado para devolver eso, pero he probado distintas modificaciones y no encuentro como devolver todos. He podido devolver sólo 1, pero necesito obtener toda la lista para usarla en otros métodos. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes colocar que tu metodo devuelva un array [] y devolver el mismo objeto que tu llenaste.

```
public LightObject[] GenerateLightsObjects()
{
    // Obtención del JSON pidiendo la variable jsonlights al Lightipscript
    GameObject a = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
    LightsIpScript b = a.GetComponent<LightsIpScript>();

    // Obtenemos el JSON
    jsonLights = b.jsonLights;

    // Obtenemos la CANTIDAD de elementos del JSON
    jsonTotalLights = b.jsonTotalOfLights;

    // Se almacena en un diccionario los objetos del JSON
    var dataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Light>>(jsonLights);

    // Almacenar el nombre de todas las bombillas
    ReadAndGetNameOfParentsFromJson(jsonLights);

    // Generar objetos de las luces
    LightObject[] lightsObjects = new LightObject[jsonTotalLights];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonTotalLights; i++)
    {
        string bombillaActual = listOfParents[i];

        lightsObjects[i] = new LightObject() {
            lightType = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].Type,
            lightOn = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].State.On,
            lightNumber = bombillaActual,
            lightHue = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].State.Hue,
            lightBri = dataDeserialized[bombillaActual].State.Bri
        };

    }

    // SACAR POR CONSOLA LA LISTA DE BOMBILLAS
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonTotalLights; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("-- BOMBILLA: "+lightsObjects[i].lightNumber);
        Debug.Log("-- TIPO DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightType);
        Debug.Log("-- COLOR DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightHue);
        Debug.Log("-- BRILLO DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightBri);
        Debug.Log("-- ESTADO DE BOMBILLA: " + lightsObjects[i].lightOn);
        Debug.Log("valor de la I: "+i);
    }

    return lightsObjects;
}
```

Comment: Pero dentro se están generando multiples objetos, no termino de entender como retornar todos, incluso basándome en tu ejemplo no me permiiría retornar lightsObjects por no ser del mismo tipo. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Edite la respuesta, si te es correcta, marcala como tal.

Comment: Buenas de nuevo ramiro, stackoverflow no me permite marcarla como correcta hasta pasar los 4 minutos, me ha servido, muchas gracias. Ya está marcada, de nuevo, gracias.